# global.asax and classic ASP?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, global-asax, global.asa

Now please excuse me if this is a stupid question - BUT...  In my ASP.NET apps, I have a global.asax file that catches an error and emails me the details.  'Could' I put the global.asax in the root of a classic ASP file and if there was an ASP error it would trigger the global.asax?

Again sorry if this is a dumb question.. If not any ideas on how I could re-create something like this for classic ASP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Classic ASP, you have the [global.asa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316.aspx) file to achieve similar functionality to what global.asax does in ASP.NET

For example

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">


Sub Application_OnStart

    'Application logic to run on start

End Sub

</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new global.asa file for your classic ASP application.

Answer (score 0):

There is global.asa for classic asp.